# Heading and total style in Excel 2007 using PHPExcel

Tags: php, excel-2007, phpexcel

Is it possible to apply a *heading style (especially heading 3 as in excel 2007)* and *total style (as in excel 2007)* in a cell in Excel 2007 using [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/downloads/get/212184) as shown in the following [snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1KD4.png)?

[image]

I applied these styles after generating it (as can be seen in the *Shipping Address*, *Billing Address* and *Total* cells). Tried on Google for a long time but couldn't find it therefore, I presumably believed that they might not be supported by PHPExcel. Is there a way to do so using PHPExcel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel's "Predefined styles" aren't built into PHPExcel, although it wouldn't be too difficult to emulate.

You can define a style array to replicate any of Excel's predefined styles, and then use the applyFromArray() method to set a cell to that style.

```
$totalStyle = array(
    'borders' => array(
        'outline' => array(
            'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN,
            'color' => array('argb' => 'FF000000'),
        ),
    ),
);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A4:C4')->applyFromArray($totalStyle);
```

All you need to do is work out the individual components of each pre-defined Excel style, and define the style array accordingly.

Comment: From your suggestion, I forgot about these styles, since I'm right now unable to reach such a long study. Thank you.